# Using StringUtils.isEmpty without losing compiler warnings about null pointers

Tags: java, compiler-warnings, apache-commons, findbugs, null-pointer

Instead of the usual `if (myString == null || myString.equals(""))` I tend to prefer using the `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils` class and do `if (StringUtils.isEmpty(myString))`.

However this - at least the way I'm doing it - comes with a gigantic downside: because FindBugs - or the compiler warning mechanism, f. ex. from Eclipse - will no longer see the explicit null-check, it will no longer consider `myString` as potentially null, so it will no longer raise the warnings about potential (or sure) null pointers on it, and those warnings are extremely useful in my view.

Example (ADDED):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class TestWarning
{
    void testWarning(String myString)
    {
        //if (myString == null || myString.equals("")) // With this, the last line shows the warning.
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(myString)) // With this, no warning.
        {
            // Anything.
        }
        int x = myString.length(); // Warning is here: "Potential null pointer access: The variable myString may be null at this location"
    }
}
```

So I'm just trying to make sure that there is no way to eliminate or minimize this downside so that one can use `StringUtils.isEmpty` and still get the null pointer warnings. Maybe some annotation like `@Nullcheck` to add to the `isEmpty` method or something else ?

ADDED: For ex., would it be feasible to create a custom annotation like `@Nullcheck`, add it to the arg of `isEmpty` like `public static boolean isEmpty(@Nullcheck String str)` just to indicate that the method does a null-check on that arg, and make so that the compiler warning mechanism or FindBugs treat a `if (StringUtils.isEmpty(myString))` just like an explicit null-check ?

Comment: StringUtils.isEmpty() handles null so why should FindBugs raise a "possible null" warning? I am not getting your issue here...

Comment: What warning of null pointers are you worried about? Can you explain that a bit more? Do you want a warning that it might throw a NPE when trying to check something like this: `StringUtils.isEmpty(null)`? Because if that's the case, then you needn't worry about it as `StringUtils.isEmpty()` handles `null` by itself and thus *FindBugs* will not bug you with unnecessary warnings. [Read the docs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)) for more info.

Comment: I'm not worried about a null pointer inside `isEmpty`; it's just that if I do `if (myString == null)` and some lines below - outside that `if` - I do for ex. `myString.length()` I will get a compiler warning of a potential null pointer on `myString.length()`. I would not get that warning if instead of `if (myString == null)` I do `if (StringUtils.isEmpty(myString))`

Comment: A compiler and even tools like FindBugs have limits and you just found one. Basically that is why you as a programmer need to use the brain you have :)

Comment: Right. But that would apply to a lot of constructs and tools designed to minimize mistakes - accidental or due to ignorance - and I kind of like that ;)

Comment: Please post a working example and mark the line where you expect a warning. It sounds like you found a bug if the usage of the variable is outside the `if` block. Better to post the actual code than describe it with prose.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, just that with `if (myString == null)` the compiler or FindBugs understand that `myString` can be null, while with `if (StringUtils.isEmpty(myString))` they don't understand that, which I think is fair enough. However I added the example to my question.

Comment: Why don't you simply annotate the myString argument with JSR-305 `@Nullable` (https://code.google.com/p/jsr-305/source/browse/trunk/ri/src/main/java/javax/annotation/Nullable.java?r=24) or FindBugs annotation `@CheckForNull`?

Comment: @JB Nizet : Because I didn't know about either of them :)  Thanks a lot, I'm going to try that and I will post the outcome. If it works I think yours should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I [downloaded](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsr305jar.htm) JSR-305 and tried its `@Nullable`, to no avail. I used it as per [one of their examples](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jsr-305/mU-HqM4jwtk/Hoq1uPrykHMJ).
`import javax.annotation.Nullable;`
`public class TestWarning {`
`    void testWarning(String myString) {`
`        if (isEmpty(myString)) { /* Anything. */ }`
`        int x = myString.length(); // Shows no nullness warning.`
`    }`
`    public static boolean isEmpty(@Nullable String str) {`
`        return str == null || str.length() == 0;`
`    }`
`}`

Comment: And sorry for the messy code above but I can't find ways to paste a readable code snippet in a comment. I read the help and tried several ways then the 5 minutes expired. I'm not sure how one is supposed to post code except using "Answer Your Question" which is of no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you annotate myString with @Nullable, i.e.

```
void testWarning(@Nullable String myString)
```

then at least eclipse will report a warning when you dereference it.

I agree that FindBugs should also be warning about it, but I can't get it to do so either.

Comment: That's what I tried with the example in the 10th comment of my question; it didn't work in Eclipse but maybe that's not the code you mean. The code I posted there didn't really come out very readable, so I'm trying again here. It should be possible to paste it into an IDE and have it format the code.
`import javax.annotation.Nullable; public class TestWarning { void testWarning(String myString) { if (isEmpty(myString)) { /* Anything. */ } int x = myString.length(); /* No nullness warning */ } public static boolean isEmpty(@Nullable String str) { return str == null || str.length() == 0; }}`

Comment: If you mean that I should put the `@Nullable` in the calling code (`testWarning` method in my example), then that's not what I'm talking about. If I do so, it would be me who says that `myString` could be null. I want the compiler to infer from `if (isEmpty(myString))` that `myString` could be null, just like it would infer that from an `if (myString == null)`. I want that doing `if (isEmpty(myString))` and doing `if (myString == null)` have the same effect on the warning (that is, show the warning).

Comment: Yes, I meant to put `@Nullable` on the argument to testWarning. When you say `if (myString == null)` you are telling eclipse/findbugs that you know that myString might be null. If that test isn't there, another way to provide the same information is to mark myString as @Nullable. When you call `isEmpty`, even if its argument is marked @Nullable, you're not telling it that.  It accepts non-null parameters, but that doesn't mean you think myString might be null.

Comment: Understood, thanks. Using `@Nullable` in that way would be a reasonable compromise; not as good as having the compiler figuring out by itself that `myString` can be null as it does with `if (myString == null)` but that's probably the closest one can get.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you get a potential null pointer warning really depends on how good the static code analyzer is. Logically, if you use

```
if (myString == null || myString.equals(""))
```

your code expect myString to be null. In the subsequent line, however, you dereference myString. The static code analyzer sees these two facts, and create a null pointer warning.

If you use

```
if (StringUtils.isEmpty(myString))
```

your code does not say whether it expects myString to be null. The static code analyzer, thus, does not generate a null pointer warning. The static code analyzer can certainly choose to generate a null pointer warning, but this will produce a lot of false positives, because it needs to assume that inputs to any method may be null.

Comment: Agreed, that is the point. So I'm wondering whether it's possible to annotate `isEmpty` signature to let the compiler know that `if (StringUtils.isEmpty(myString))` is as much of a null-check on `myString` as `if (myString == null)` is.
I tried the JSR-305 `@Nullable` suggestion above but that `@Nullable` does not seem to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse code analysis can also evaluate external null annotations (since 4.5.0). More information is available at https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core/Null_Analysis/External_Annotations.